# Текстовый (ASCII?) autoincrement в DBF

Tags: delphi, dbase, dbf

Программа работает с DBF базой dBase

В поле `key` используется непонятный autoincrement, не привычный числовой, а с ASCII символами.

```
!!!Dљy*qU
!!!Dљy*q€
!!!Dљy&[N
!!!Dљy&`h
!!!Dљy&¦/
!!!Dљy&‡§
!!!Dљy&¦k
```

[image: http://www.radikal.ru]

Или например

[image: http://www.radikal.ru]

Помогите реализовать этот пример на Delphi или PHP, чтобы я мог добавлять свои записи в БД.

Comment: это на просто int больше всего похоже, скорее всего в базе как-то получилось что тип этого поля указан как символьный а не int, либо это ваш браузер базы данных глючит.

Comment: Нет не генерит, в старых версиях dBase (а это именно устаревшая версия) autoincrement не поддерживается, т.е. программа сама смотрит последнюю запись в базе и увеличивает значение. Поле текстовое.
В других таблицах, где гораздо меньше значений, можно проследить такую последовательность:
aa
ab
ac
ad
....
a*
a(
a)

Answer (score 2):

Читайте мануал, "autoincrement" для того и "auto", что за ним следит сам движок базы. При добавлении новой записи, это поле не нужно передавать, движок сам генерит для этого поля значение.

Comment: Нет не генерит, в старых версиях dBase (а это именно устаревшая версия) autoincrement не поддерживается, т.е. программа сама смотрит последнюю запись в базе и увеличивает значение. Поле текстовое.
В других таблицах, где гораздо меньше значений, можно проследить такую последовательность:
aa
ab
ac
ad
....
a*
a(
a)

Comment: Ок. Давайте по порядку. Что пробовали и что не получилось?